# Tab-Completion of Matlab commands in Sublime Text 2?

Tags: matlab, sublimetext2, tab-completion

I've recently started using Sublime Text 2 to edit my Matlab files (.m) as I was frustrated with its build-in editor.

I was wondering, is there anyway to have the **tab-completion** of the native editor (for functions and commands) in Sublime Text?

Comment: Out of interest, why are you frustrated with the built-in editor?

Comment: @SamRoberts: It's basically Visual Studio's fault with its features. If you consider built-in-editor an "editor", then it does the job. But as and IDE (like VS or Eclipse) it's certainly lacking. No refactoring, no templates, rubbish UI (fonts, colors,...) also  tab completion is bare bones without helping that much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you'll have to create the snippets for those matlab functions you want tab-completed in ST2.  As far as I know, there is not an existing library available.

For example, from my ST2:

[image]

Comment: How can I add snippets? Should I do it 1 by 1 or can I add a list of commands at once?

Comment: Snippets can be created most easily by selecting the "Tools-> New Snippet" menu.  Look at one of the existing matlab snippets to get the feel for how to create a new one.  Further, look here for a [nice guide to making snippets](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/extensibility/snippets.html)

Answer (score 5):

Inspired by Flom Enol's question, I created a library of snippets for the MATLAB standard toolbox.  They can be found [here](https://github.com/AGS-Knight/matlab-snipp)

Currently, there are roughly `4000` snippets in this library.  I am hoping to add additional toolboxes and incorporate the libraries into ST2's "Package Control" in the near future.

Hope these are useful.

Comment: I've since added the tab-completion snippets for the statistics toolbox